# Why is the ProgressHandler not increasing the argument's value when using the operator ++ within?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

When using the class ***ProgressHandler*** the result was not as I have expected. There is an async-method running in an interation. Every cycle a counter is increased by 1 using the ***operator ++***. The main thread will be informed about the progress by using the method ***Report()***.

The problem is, that the cycle counter passed on to the ***ProgressHandler*** is incorrect. It is the ***correct value - 1***. If the iteration is running 10x cycles the main thread displays 9x cycles.

```
_ProgressHandler = new Progress<int>(value =>
{
   CycleCounter = value;
   Console.WriteLine("***** ProgressHandler: " + CycleCounter);
});
var progress = _ProgressHandler as IProgress<int>;

// code left out in this view

progress?.Report(i++);
```

## Steps to understand the issue

- adding ***WriteLine()*** to show the current value of the field used inside the iteration
- adding ***WriteLine()*** to the ProgressHandler to show the received value
- adding some ***Thread.Sleep()*** to rule out timing issues
- changing the use of the ***operator ++***

## A solution (that I don't understand)

using code like this is showing the incorrect value:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("before i=" + i);
    progress?.Report(i++);
    Console.WriteLine("after  i=" + i);
    Console.WriteLine("==========");
} while (i < 10);
```

using code like this is working properly:

```c
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("before i=" + i);
    i++;
    progress?.Report(i);
    Console.WriteLine("after  i=" + i);
    Console.WriteLine("==========");
} while (i < 10);
```

## My questions

Since I am going the first steps in using multi-threading, I would like to understand this issue. Deeper understanding would help to avoid future issues in my coding progress.

- Why is the application not working properly if I use the ***operator ++*** as an argument within the method, like ***progress?.Report(i++)***?
- Is it a timing issue?
- Is it thread related?
- Is it something I even don't think of, because of just having basic knowledge?
- Is there a smarter way to update the main thread?

Any information, help or comment is appreciated a lot.

Here is the unabbreviated code:

```
using CodingSolutions.Model;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CodingSolutions.ViewModel
{
    public partial class MainConsole : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region ***** Field *****
        private Progress<int> _ProgressHandler;
        private int _CycleCounter;
        #endregion

        #region ***** Property *****
        public int CycleCounter { get => _CycleCounter; set => _CycleCounter = value; }
        #endregion

        #region ***** Constructor *****
        public MainConsole()
        {
            _ProgressHandler = new Progress<int>(value =>
            {
                CycleCounter = value;
                Console.WriteLine("***** ProgressHandler: " + CycleCounter);
            });
            var progress = _ProgressHandler as IProgress<int>;

            CycleCounter = 0;
            ProgressTest(progress);

            CycleCounter = 0;
            ProgressTestAsync(progress);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("\n***** Press Enter To Leave *****");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        #endregion

        #region ***** Private Method *****
        private async void ProgressTestAsync(IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            int i = 0;

            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => 
                {
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("before i=" + i);
                        progress?.Report(i++);
                        Console.WriteLine("after  i=" + i);
                        Console.WriteLine("==========");
                    } while (i < 10);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ExceptionMessage: " + e.Message);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("***** Async EndOfLoop CyclyCounter: " + CycleCounter);
            Console.WriteLine("***** Async EndOfLoop field i     : " + i);

            Console.WriteLine("\n***** Press Enter To Continue *****");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }

        private void ProgressTest(IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            int i = 0;

            try
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("before i=" + i);
                    progress?.Report(i++);
                    Console.WriteLine("after  i=" + i);
                    Console.WriteLine("==========");
                } while (i < 10);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ExceptionMessage: " + e.Message);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("***** EndOfLoop CyclyCounter: " + CycleCounter);
            Console.WriteLine("***** EndOfLoop field i     : " + i);

            Console.WriteLine("\n***** Press Enter To Continue *****");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `++i` so the value is incremented *before* passing it to Report()

Comment: @HansPassant
THIS, i will never forget! Thanks a lot, Hans! Such a basic syntax, but I have never used it before.

Comment: @karwenzman - `i++` means return the value that `i` currently has and then increment it by one. `++i` means increment `i` by one and then return the new value of `i`.

Comment: @Enigmativity - on page 91 in my school book this arithmetic operation is explained; now, I do have a nice example why this matters; these four hours of investigation have carved this fact into my brain :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. Thanks to the comments, I keep this is my mind.

Instead of `progress?.Report(i++)` I should have used `progress?.Report(++i)`. This is solving my question.

`i++` is passing `i` to `Report()` and then incrementing it by 1.
`++i` is incrementing `i` by 1 and then passing it to `Report()`.

This is how the code looks like, now.

```
using CodingSolutions.Model;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CodingSolutions.ViewModel
{
    public partial class MainConsole : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Progress<int> _ProgressHandler;
        private int _CycleCounter;

        public int CycleCounter { get => _CycleCounter; set => _CycleCounter = value; }

        public MainConsole()
        {
            _ProgressHandler = new Progress<int>(value =>
            {
                CycleCounter = value;
                Console.WriteLine("***** ProgressHandler: " + CycleCounter);
            });
            var progress = _ProgressHandler as IProgress<int>;

            CycleCounter = 0;
            ProgressTest(progress);

            CycleCounter = 0;
            ProgressTestAsync(progress);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("\n***** Press Enter To Leave *****");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private async void ProgressTestAsync(IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            int i = 0;

            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => 
                {
                    do
                    {
                        progress?.Report(++i);
                    } while (i < 10);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ExceptionMessage: " + e.Message);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("***** Async EndOfLoop CyclyCounter: " + CycleCounter);
            Console.WriteLine("***** Async EndOfLoop field i     : " + i);

            Console.WriteLine("\n***** Press Enter To Continue *****");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }

        private void ProgressTest(IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            int i = 0;

            try
            {
                do
                {
                    progress?.Report(++i);
                } while (i < 10);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ExceptionMessage: " + e.Message);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("***** EndOfLoop CyclyCounter: " + CycleCounter);
            Console.WriteLine("***** EndOfLoop field i     : " + i);

            Console.WriteLine("\n***** Press Enter To Continue *****");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```